# How do i specify that hello-world-1-1.rpm must be installed before upgrading to hello-world-1-2.rpm

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

header of hello-world-1-1.rpm is as follows

```
Name:       hello-world
Version:    1
Release:    1
Summary:    Most simple RPM package
License:    FIXME
Provides: hello-world = %{version}-%{release}
```

header of hello-world-1-2.rpm is as follows

```
Name:       hello-world
Version:    1
Release:    2
Summary:    Most simple RPM package
License:    FIXME
Requires: hello-world = 1-1
Provides: hello-world = %{version}-%{release}
```

Comment: What do you want to obtain? You want both version 1.1 and 1.2 to be installed together? Or you want to prevent a user from installing 1.2 without first installing 1.1? In the latter case that does not seem a good design; since it is not - or very difficultly - possible with rpm and will cause you much headaches for update; what when you create version 1.3?

Comment: @ChrisMaes thankyou :)